# Momentary popup of information

Tags: popup

I have seen that emacs provides some kind of popup menus.  Had a go at `momentary-string-display` and `message-box`.  `momentary-string-display` displays text in the buffer, whereas `message-box` displays a box with button.

Can one momentarily show a kind of popup similar to `autocomplete` or `company`, something similar to popup tooltip with a coloured background colour, so I do not have to switch to another buffer to see the information I want printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of packages that provide functionality to display inline information in the buffer. The builtin package `eldoc` will display information about the current function at point below the modeline, which is often sufficient, but not quite a popup.

The most common approach for selectively displaying information inline or near the current point, is to use an [overlay](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlays.html), which are attributes attached to a range of characters. Take a look at how company.el uses the functions `overlay-get` and `overlay-put` to attach properties to the text near a popup, and change the face of the text depending on where the point is.

If you are looking for a library that encapsulates this behavior using overlays, take a look at [popup.el](https://github.com/auto-complete/popup-el), or [quick-peek](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/quick-peek). There are other approaches as well, [eldoc-box](https://github.com/casouri/eldoc-box) appears to be using a childframe triggered by an overlay. That said, many of the help systems in emacs provide context information in a temporary popup buffer. It may be worth trying that approach first.

Providing more context on what you intend to use the popup for might help in selecting which of these is appropriate for your task.

Comment: With temporary popup buffer, do you mean something like `(with-output-to-temp-buffer "*protocuneus*"  (print summary-string))`?

Comment: Yea or with a helper that calls `(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create name) (mode) (insert content))`. Take a look at the function `help--window-setup` and `help-form-show` in `help.el`, I believe that's how `C-h f` generates a help buffer.

Comment: Do you know how to switch to the temporary help buffer when I call the help-function from another buffer?  Currently doing `M-x myhelp` shows the temporary buffer but does not switch to it.

Comment: `switch-to-buffer` or `switch-to-buffer-other-window`?

Comment: What do you think of `pop-to-buffer` compared to `switch-to-buffer`?

Comment: I think `switch-to-buffer` uses `pop-to-buffer` under the hood, but it might that `pop-to-buffer` is what you want. I took a quick look at `cider-popup` which I've used previously that that had a variable to switch between `pop-to-buffer` and `display-buffer`. The latter is used to show a buffer without selecting, ie the `myhelp` example you mentioned above.